# xymatrix and commutative diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

Using `xymatrix` to get a commutative diagram `$X=X$`, I want to make the morphism identify as `=`, not `\xymatrix {X\ar[r]^{id}X}`.

How can I get this?

Comment: If I remember well, `\ar@{=}[r]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard arrow is `->`, but you can change them quite easily:

```
\ar@{->}[r] % standard, can be input \ar[r]
\ar@{->>}[r] % double head
\ar@{=>}[r] % double stem and head
\ar@{=}[r] % double stem (equality)
```

and several others.

Comment: I am really appreciated.

Comment: if I want to make the morphism is isomorphism not identity.This way seems can't achieve.How to chage?Thank you

Comment: @Sky There's nothing like that and for good reasons: a very long tilde is among the ugliest things I can imagine.